# Defining Strings as Null is better or as Empty Strings

Tags: java

I come from a C#.net background and whenever I had a string I was declaring it as `String.Empty`
Now I am looking at a Java code from a co-worker and he has declared his strings in a method like this:

```
String myStr = null;
```

I don't like it, and even worse, he is assigning values to these strings in an "IF" block where it may or may not even qualify, and then at the end of the method he is calling a `myStr.length()` on them.

So my question is what is a preferred way in Java? do you think is it better to define them as `String.Empty` OR leave them as `null` and do a `null` check just before calling `.length()` on them?

Comment: Do you mean `myStr = "";` by `String.Empty`?

Comment: Won't that depend on what you are doing?  Given that `null` and `empty` are different it could allow for more options in the flow.  However, in general, I find it is better to NOT use null unless you have to have it.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad : Yes, an empty string. In .NET we could use String.Empty so I was just used to that syntax but yes that's what I meant to say.

Comment: That pattern of assigning a local variable a null value at the point of declaration and then reassigning it later under various circumstances is one i see quite a bit. It is a *bad* idea, because it defeats the compiler's ability to check whether it has been properly ("definitely") assigned. As you have observed, it leaves you in danger of NullPointerExceptions. I take it as a reliable sign of an unreliable programmer!

Comment: and about another point in using null as assignment u can use it with quite of less worry about being thrown null pointer exception as there are many tools like(FindBugs, checker framework which uses annotations to check for the possibilities of NullPointerException and warns you during compilation itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, using `null` values is a bad idea, especially if they are returned from a method or passed to another method. Using the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is better, and in a string's case the Null Object is an empty string. By consistently avoiding nulls, the probability of getting a NullPointerException gets smaller and the code becomes more readable (this is discussed at length in [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) chapter 7, pages 110-112).

In Java `String s = ""` does not allocate any memory, because the JVM will have interned the string literal, so there isn't even a performance difference (and even if there were, it would be a premature optimization).

Comment: The Null Object pattern defeats the compiler flow analysis that triggers 'variable not initialized' and also the use of sentinels unless you can show that the null object cannot occur in-band.

Comment: @esko valid point but that intern is a static method of String class so the strings created with it including that "" will never be garbage collected. so cost of using intern() increases linearly

Comment: @exex Wrong on all counts. 1. intern() is not a static method. 2. Even if it was, it wouldn't imply no GC. 3. Interned strings *can* be garbage collected. 4. The cost of using intern() increases linearly *with the number of distinct strings,* subject to garbage collection.

Comment: @EJP ohh my mistake- yeah that intern is not static method I saw String.intern() and interpreted it as being static

Comment: @EJP and about GC on string constants have a look on this link http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html

Comment: @exec More confusion. String literals can't be GC'd, as they are part of the program text, and saying they are interned is misleading. They are merged into the String constant pool by the compiler and the class loader, not by String.intern(). It is the results of String.intern() that can be GC'd.

Comment: Returning blank string is in-band signaling is a sign of code smell. If a method's result is "none", then null is the appropriate value. Blanks string is just a magic value for those that are too lazy to do a null check.

Comment: The OP was asking for "what is a preferred way". In some situations using null might be reasonable, but without seeing any code it's not possible to say whether that exception is warranted. null is a code smell and should be avoided by default.

Answer (score 4):

They both have their uses. Empty strings are in-band, i.e. can occur in the input, so they are no use as sentinels. Null is *only* useful as a sentinel. If you're going to append to it you should initialize it with "" of course. If you're going to immediately reassign it there's no need to provide any value at all, and you should probably combine the declaration with the reassignment. I see far too much of this:

```
String s = new String();
s = "some string";
```

All this tells me is that somebody doesn't understand the language.

Comment: +1 on the in-band. If the return value from a method is "no value", then null is the appropriate value.

Answer (score 3):

thought both are applicable for different scenarios, assigning it null will be better(saves memory and less error prone) provided  you later on set some string to that else you will be getting a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

An empty String is often a sign that you should either be using a `StringBuilder` if you're appending (which is a common case). A `null` reference is 'better' because it uses less memory and it's faster to check if a String is null compared to checking if it's empty. I would advice against using empty Strings instead of declaring them as null, though you should still check for null reference before you use it unless you're 100% sure that it would have been assigned a value at some stage.

Comment: The empty string is interned.  Having multiple references to empty strings doesn't cost any memory.

Comment: @paranoid +1 - gud point empty string is usable to work with append of StringBuilder

Comment: @exex Actually, I meant that empty strings are often declared as such preceding a loop where the string is 'appended' to using +=. (Bad)

Comment: @MikeSamuel That's a very good point, thanks for pointing that out. +1